# Store List in hibernate as Serializable object

Tags: java, list, hibernate-mapping

Normally we store a List in database by the hibernate mapping:

```
<list name="userItems" cascade="all" lazy="false">
    <key column="user_date_id"/>
    <index column="idx"/>
    <one-to-many class="UserItem"/>
</list>
```

Is there any other way? Can we store it as a Seializable object? Like:

```
<property name="list" column="list" type="serializable" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Hibernate Annotiations, and the trick here is to define your field as a `List` implementation like `ArrayList`. Then (like any other class implementing `Serializable` - i guess) Hibernate stores it as a `bytea` in the database.

Of course the list should only contain elements that implement `Serializable`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can directly serialize a list but if not you might create a wrapper object for the list and declare it as large object (don't know the xml variant, but it's the `@Lob` annotation). This should automatically be serialized then, since its not a string and thus not a clob but rather a blob.